# impact of critical updates 'Enable CSRF protection on GET and POST requests' & 'Require secure connections (HTTPS)'

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, administration

We are in the process of activating critical updates in our production environment.
1) Require secure connections (HTTPS)
2) Enable CSRF protection on GET and POST requests

Can someone explains me in brief components what might be affected if these are activated.
Also what is need to be cross verified for convenience.

Feedback is appreciated..